# Iterate through objects of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I have this JSON data and I want to iterate over all objects like uf, ivp en so on.

```
{
"version": "1.5.0",
"autor": "mindicador.cl",
"fecha": "2018-10-31T13:00:00.000Z",
"uf": {
"codigo": "uf",
"nombre": "Unidad de fomento (UF)",
"unidad_medida": "Pesos",
"fecha": "2018-10-31T04:00:00.000Z",
"valor": 27432.1
},
"ivp": {
"codigo": "ivp",
"nombre": "Indice de valor promedio (IVP)",
"unidad_medida": "Pesos",
"fecha": "2018-10-31T04:00:00.000Z",
"valor": 28540.81
},
}
```

Right now I have this code but just give me the name of the objects I cannot access to properties

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: API_REQUEST,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#mindicador').html(JSON.stringify(data));
                    let k;
                    for (k of Object.keys(data)) {
                        if (k === 'version') continue;
                        if (k === 'autor') continue;
                        if (k === 'fecha') continue;
                        console.log(k.nombre);
                    }
                }
                ,error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                    console.log('errorMessage: ' + errorMessage);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Comment: `I cannot access to properties`  because your asking for the keys.  Have a look at `Object.entries`, this will give you the key and value.  eg.  `for ([k, v] of Object.keys(data))`  k = key, v = value

Comment: It only gives you the names of the properties because that's explicitly what you told it to do by using `Object.keys`....anyway what do you want to do when you get to the nested objects (e.g. uf) - you want to recursively loop through all the sub-properties, or not? Is the structure predictable every time, or will you not know the property names in advance? The answers to those questions will affect how complicated the solution is.

Answer (score 1):

By iterating through the `Object.keys` of `data`, you're just looking at an array of strings. If you want to access that key's value, you can access it from `data` with bracket notation:

```
for (const k of Object.keys(data)) {
    console.log(data[k]);
}
```

Or, instead of using `Object.keys`, you can iterate the object with with a `for ...in` loop:

```
for (const k in data) {
    console.log(data[k]);
}
```